# Problem with communicate docker containers on Mac OS

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-network

I have project with `docker compose` in one network `crypto-gateway` with `bridge` driver (other networks is external and use `bridge` driver too).

My `docker-compose.yml`:

```yaml
version: '3.5'

services:
    nginx:
        image: nginx:alpine
        container_name: crypto-gateway-nginx
        restart: always
        volumes:
            - '${CODE_DIR}:/code'
            - '../../certificates/crypto-gateway:/certificates:ro'
            - './nginx/conf.d/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:ro'
        networks:
            - traefik
            - crypto-gateway
        labels:
            traefik.enable: true
            traefik.frontend.rule: 'Host: crypto-gateway.local'
            traefik.port: '443'
            traefik.protocol: 'https'
            traefik.frontend.headers.SSLRedirect: true

    web:
        build:
            dockerfile: ./applications/crypto-gateway/web/Dockerfile
            context: ../../
            args:
                XDEBUG_REMOTE_HOST: "${XDEBUG_REMOTE_HOST}"
                XDEBUG_REMOTE_PORT: "${XDEBUG_REMOTE_PORT}"
        container_name: crypto-gateway-web
        restart: always
        volumes:
            - '${CODE_DIR}:/code'
            - '${SSH_HOME_DIR}:/root/.ssh'
        networks:
            - crypto-gateway

    mysql:
        image: mysql:8.0
        container_name: crypto-gateway-db
        environment:
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: Q1w2e3r4
            MYSQL_USER: crypto-gateway
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: Q1w2e3r4
            MYSQL_DATABASE: crypto_gateway
        ports:
            - '5400:3306'
        volumes:
            - '${DATABASE_MYSQL_SHARED_DIR}/origin:/var/lib/mysql'
            - './mysql/initdb.d:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d'
        command: mysqld --innodb-use-native-aio=0 --sql-mode="ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION"
        networks:
            - databases
            - crypto-gateway

    rabbitmq:
        image: rabbitmq:3-management
        container_name: crypto-gateway-rabbitmq
        restart: always
        environment:
            RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER: guest
            RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS: guest
        networks:
            - traefik
            - crypto-gateway
        labels:
            traefik.enable: true
            traefik.frontend.rule: 'Host: rabbitmq.crypto-gateway.local'
            traefik.port: '15672'
            traefik.protocol: 'http'
            traefik.frontend.headers.SSLRedirect: true

    vault:
        image: hashicorp/vault
        container_name: crypto-gateway-vault
        restart: always
        environment:
            VAULT_DEV_ROOT_TOKEN_ID: Q1w2e3r4
            VAULT_DEV_LISTEN_ADDRESS: '0.0.0.0:8200'
        networks:
            - traefik
            - crypto-gateway
        labels:
            traefik.enable: true
            traefik.frontend.rule: 'Host: vault.crypto-gateway.local'
            traefik.port: '8200'
            traefik.protocol: 'http'
            traefik.frontend.headers.SSLRedirect: true

    assets:
        image: node:19
        container_name: crypto-gateway-assets
        tty: true
        volumes:
            - '${CODE_DIR}:/code'
        networks:
            - crypto-gateway

networks:
    databases:
        external: true

    traefik:
        external: true

    crypto-gateway:
        driver: bridge
        name: crypto-gateway
```

After connect to `web` container I does not have connection to other container (maybe `db` or `vault` or etc..). I try to restart docker compose, and after it I have connect to one of container but not connect to other containers. After second restart, i can have connection to different container but not have connection to other containers.

I solve this problem after many restart docker compose (maybe 5-th or more times).

```
root@49d6e4698b58:/code# telnet crypto-gateway-db 3306   
telnet: could not resolve crypto-gateway-db/3306: Name or service not known
root@49d6e4698b58:/code# telnet crypto-gateway-vault 8200
Trying 172.27.0.3...
Connected to crypto-gateway-vault.
Escape character is '^]'.
```

Previously (4-5 month ago) docker work correct and I not have this problem.

Info about OS:

- Mac OS: Ventura 13.5 (MacBook PRO M2)
- Docker Desktop: 4.21.1
- Docker client version: 24.0.2
- Docker server version: 24.0.2-38-g8e70a1b23e
- Use VPN (tunnelblick)

Maybe problem with docker DNS, but I not known how debug it.

Comment: Just in the name of cleaning things up a little, I might try deleting _all_ of the `networks:` blocks in the file, and probably the `container_name:` lines too.  Can you connect to the Compose service names like `db` and `vault`?  (If you still have the same problem, [edit]ing the question to remove the unnecessary details would help understand the question a little better.)